# Maui windows application Label text not updating in UI

Tags: c#, mvvm, maui, observablecollection

My purpose is to update ping status on UI. I am using MVVM pattern in MAUI desktop application.

In **MainPage.xaml.cs**

```cs
namespace MauiSampleApp
{
    public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
    {
        //int count = 0;

        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void OnCounterClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Shell.Current.GoToAsync("/Sample1");
            SampleM sampleM = new SampleM();
            sampleM.StartThreadfunction();
        }
    }
}
```

**Sample1.xaml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="MauiSampleApp.View.Sample1"
             xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:MauiSampleApp.ViewModel"             
             xmlns:toolkit="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2022/maui/toolkit"
             
             Title="Sample1">
    <ContentPage.BindingContext>
        <vm:SampleVM/>
    </ContentPage.BindingContext>
    <VerticalStackLayout>
        <Label 
            Text="{Binding ServerStatus}"
            VerticalOptions="Center" 
            HorizontalOptions="Center" />
    </VerticalStackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

**SampleVM.cs**

```cs
namespace MauiSampleApp.ViewModel
{
    public partial class SampleVM : ObservableObject
    {
        [ObservableProperty]        
        public string serverStatus = "Test";

        public void setServerStatus(string currStatus)
        {
            ServerStatus = currStatus;
        }
    }
}
```

**SampleM.cs**

```cs
namespace MauiSampleApp.Model
{
    internal class SampleM
    {
        public void StartThreadfunction()
        {
            Thread t1 = new Thread(() => CheckServerConnectivity());
            t1.Start();
        }

        public static void CheckServerConnectivity()
        {
            SampleVM sampleVM = new SampleVM();
            while (true)
            {
                try
                {
                    Ping x = new Ping();
                    PingReply reply = x.Send(IPAddress.Parse("192.168.x.xxx"));
                    if (reply.Status == IPStatus.Success)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Address is accessible");
                        sampleVM.setServerStatus("connected");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Address is not accessible");
                        sampleVM.setServerStatus("Disconnected");
                        //break;
                    }
                    Thread.Sleep(5000);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Exception message : {0}", ex.Message);
                    sampleVM.setServerStatus(ex.Message);
                    break;
                }
            }
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

Label value "Test" display but thread status not updating. In debug mode "ServerStatus" is updated but not shown in UI.which step is wrong am i doing?

[image]

Comment: This line `SampleVM sampleVM = new SampleVM();` creates a new instance of `SampleVM` while your Page binds to a different instance. Apart from that, your code is not MVVM compliant. The Model shouldn't know about the ViewModel.

Answer (score 1):

## MVVM Pattern

You claim you're applying the [MVVM pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/architecture/maui/mvvm), but actually you're not. Here you can find more information about the [MVVM pattern and data binding in MAUI](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/maui/xaml/fundamentals/mvvm).

The dependency graph in an MVVM application typically looks like this (where the arrow means "depends on"):

```
View -> ViewModel -> Model
```

In your case, the dependencies look like this:

```
View -> Model -> ViewModel
```

The Model usually holds data while the ViewModel is where the business logic lives, you have that confused.

## Problem 1: BindingContext

Now, your code doesn't work, because you have two instances of the ViewModel, one that is created inside the XAML and used as the `BindingContext`

```xml
<ContentPage.BindingContext>
    <vm:SampleVM/>
</ContentPage.BindingContext>
```

and another one that is instantiated *(incorrectly!)* by what you call "Model":

```cs
public static void CheckServerConnectivity()
{
    SampleVM sampleVM = new SampleVM();

    //...
}
```

The UI doesn't know anything about this second instance, it is in no way related to the instance that is used as the `BindingContext`.

Note that your method also must not be `static`, because it needs to access instance data *(see solution below)*.

## Problem 2: Multiple Threads

You're creating a new instance of `SampleM` everytime a button gets clicked and each time, you start a new thread, which will lead to many concurrent threads, this will have unforeseen side effects like potential deadlocks, race conditions, etc.

I'm not going to go into detail here, because your current problem is related to updating the UI. However, you shouldn't be starting your own threads, it's better to schedule a task on the thread pool instead, if it needs to run in the background, e.g. by calling [Task.Run()](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.run). This isn't ideal either, but threading and asynchronous programming are an entire class of topics on their own.

## Solution

To fix the binding issue and make the app MVVM compliant, you should first swap Model and ViewModel around and then create only a single instance of your ViewModel which you then use as the `BindingContext` (last step):

**Model**

```cs
namespace MauiSampleApp.Model
{
    public partial class SampleM : ObservableObject
    {
        [ObservableProperty]        
        private string serverStatus = "Test";

        public void setServerStatus(string currStatus)
        {
            ServerStatus = currStatus;
        }
    }
}
```

**ViewModel**

```cs
namespace MauiSampleApp.ViewModel
{
    internal class SampleVM
    {
        public SampleM Model { get; } = new();

        public void StartThreadfunction()
        {
            Task.Run(CheckServerConnectivity);
        }

        private void CheckServerConnectivity()
        {
            while (true)
            {
                try
                {
                    Ping x = new Ping();
                    PingReply reply = x.Send(IPAddress.Parse("192.168.x.xxx"));
                    if (reply.Status == IPStatus.Success)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Address is accessible");
                        Model.setServerStatus("connected");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Address is not accessible");
                        Model.setServerStatus("Disconnected");
                        //break;
                    }
                    Thread.Sleep(5000);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Exception message : {0}", ex.Message);
                    Model.setServerStatus(ex.Message);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**View**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="MauiSampleApp.View.Sample1"
             xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:MauiSampleApp.ViewModel"             
             xmlns:toolkit="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2022/maui/toolkit"
             
             Title="Sample1">
    <VerticalStackLayout>
        <Label 
            Text="{Binding Model.ServerStatus}"
            VerticalOptions="Center" 
            HorizontalOptions="Center" />
    </VerticalStackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

```cs
namespace MauiSampleApp
{
    public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            SampleVM sampleVM = new SampleVM();
            sampleVM.StartThreadfunction();
            BindingContext = sampleVM;
        }
    }
}
```

***Note** that this will only fix the binding issue and prevent multiple threads from being started, it doesn't fix any other design or threading issues.*

Comment: Thank you @julian to explain MVVM concept and correcting my mistakes. I have modified code as per you suggestion. But UI issue still not resolve.

Comment: @HAC Try using a thread pool task instead of starting a thread manually. I've updated my answer. Your `CheckServerConnectivity()` method cannot be *static* and it should be scheduled using `Task.Run()` to run on a thread pool thread.